# TableView: locationInView returning wrong value for cells with UITableViewAutomaticDimension height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a table view with dynamic row height:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
  return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 80.0
}
```

This table view has an associated gesture recognizer to handle long press on it's cells and when this happens I obtain the location of the touch in the view like this:

```
let locationInView = recognizer.locationInView(tableView)
let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(locationInView)
```

The problem is that the locationInView is returning a wrong value when the cells a cell is displayed for the first time, the next time it returns the right value. This is happening because of the automatic dimension of the cells but I haven't been able to fix it. Any clues?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would it be better if the gesture recognizer were on each individual _cell_?

Comment: I also tried that but had the same result :s. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I've noticed some peculiarities about the whole automatic variable height thing that I don't like, so perhaps the best solution is not to use it. We did very well without it for years, after all. You have to implement `heightForRow` and do the measurement work yourself beforehand for all your cells, but it's not hard.